# How to get file URL using Aws::S3::Client having bucket and filename?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have the following code to get the file data:

```
client = Aws::S3::Client.new(***settings***)
client.get_object(bucket: Settings.aws.data_migrations.s3_bucket, key: filename)
```

It returns `Aws::S3::Types::GetObjectOutput`

Is it possible to get file URL using the bucket and filename?

Answer (score 0):

url is:
https://.s3-.amazonaws.com/

example:
https://testbucket.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sample_folder/image.jpeg

Comment: note the object should be public in order to download.